# Why display this error "is not accessible in this context because it is 'ProtectedFriend'" when i create a table for excel? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created a table for export in .xlsx file, when i create my table give me that error at row when i try to give table Row like that:

```
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable()

Dim myDataColumn0 As New System.Data.DataColumn
myDataColumn0.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
myDataColumn0.ColumnName = "CW"
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn0)

Dim myDataColumn1 As New System.Data.DataColumn
myDataColumn1.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
myDataColumn1.ColumnName = "Count of open orders"
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn1)

Dim myDataColumn2 As New System.Data.DataColumn
myDataColumn2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
myDataColumn2.ColumnName = "Count of closed order"
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn2)

Dim myDataColumn3 As New System.Data.DataColumn
myDataColumn3.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
myDataColumn3.ColumnName = "Sum of ECE units open"
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn3)

Dim myDataColumn4 As New System.Data.DataColumn
myDataColumn4.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
myDataColumn4.ColumnName = "Sum of ECE units closed"
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn4)


Dim myDataRow As New System.Data.DataRow

Return myDataTable
```

O line

> Dim myDataRow As New System.Data.DataRow

Give me error from title, but why? How can I proceed?

Comment: Use the `NewRow` method of the intended destination DataTable; it will create a row with the correctly typed columns.  A generic, plan `New DataRow` would require us to tediously add each column, correctly typed and in the correct order.

Comment: Ok, is good but how i give value?

Comment: `myNewDR(n) = value`  really hard to to with intellisense getting in the way and all.  You probably want to rethink storing a *Count of * anything as string.